# How to bundle a Web Component with a CSS, HTML, and JS file using Rollup?

Tags: javascript, bundle, web-component, rollupjs, lwc

I have a Lightning Web Component (LWC) which has a `.html`, `.css`, and `.js` file.
I wish to measure the bundle size of this one component.

To do so, I wish to bundle my component using `rollup`. And then measure the bundled file size using some 3rd party library.

But how do I use `rollup` in this context? I see there are many plugins required... I could not seem to find examples online where the developer is bundling all three: `.html`, `.css`, and `.js`. What would my `rollup.config.js` file consume for its plugins, and what would this file even look like?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the exact answer you want, but I think it would save you a lot of headaches in the long run.

I would highly recommend using [vite](https://vitejs.dev/). Not only does it use rollup under the hood, but it will also will show you the size of the bundle when you build it.

Considering that you are making a web component, you would likely build it as a library, and there is a guide for that [here](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#library-mode) that details exactly how to do that.

Without seeing the code, I don't thing I can give you much more help, but their documentation is very good, and it is very easy to set up with npm, yarn, and pnpm.